# Faster way to concat dataframes with different columns vertically

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to concat two huge dataframes (around 15GB) like the following:

a_df:

```
            A       B       C       D
2018-10-16  a16     b16     c16     d16
2018-10-17  a17     b17     c17     d17
2018-10-18  a18     b18     c18     d18
2018-10-19  a19     b19     c19     d19
2018-10-20  a20     b20     c20     d20
```

b_df:

```
            A       C       Y       Z       
2018-10-21  a21     c21     y21     z21     
2018-10-22  a22     c22     y22     z22
```

to get a final dataframe:

```
            A       B       C       D       Y       Z
2018-10-16  a16     b16     c16     d16
2018-10-17  a17     b17     c17     d17
2018-10-18  a18     b18     c18     d18
2018-10-19  a19     b19     c19     d19
2018-10-20  a20     b20     c20     d20
2018-10-21  a21             c21             y21     z21
2018-10-22  a22             c22             y22     z22
```

I am trying that code:

```
dfs = [a_df, b_df]

unique_columns = []
for df in dfs:
    for column in df.columns:
        unique_columns.append(column)
unique_columns = sorted(set(unique_columns))

same_columns_dfs = []
for df in dfs:
    empty_df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=df.index, columns=unique_columns)
    empty_df.loc[:, df.columns] = df.values
    same_columns_dfs.append(empty_df)

final_df = pd.concat(same_columns_dfs, axis=0, sort=True)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can do this in one line, no need to create other lists or empty dataframes when [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) will cover your use-case entirely:

```py
import pandas as pd
# to artificially fill a dataframe
import random

# for the purpose of transparency, here's how the dataframes were constructed
a_cols = list('ABCD')
b_cols = list('ACYZ')
a_index = [f'2018-10-{i}' for i in range(16, 21)]
b_index = [f'2018-10-{i}' for i in range(21, 23)]

# creation of the two dataframes
a = pd.DataFrame([{col: random.randint(0, 10) for col in a_cols} for i in a_index], index=a_index)
            A  B  C  D
2018-10-16  6  8  7  4
2018-10-17  5  6  2  5
2018-10-18  4  1  6  5
2018-10-19  4  3  7  9
2018-10-20  7  6  7  5

b = pd.DataFrame([{col: random.randint(0, 10) for col in b_cols} for i in b_index], index=b_index)
            A  C  Y   Z
2018-10-21  1  9  4  10
2018-10-22  1  6  4   6


# and here's your function call
pd.concat([a, b], axis=0, sort=True)
            A    B  C    D    Y     Z
2018-10-16  6  8.0  7  4.0  NaN   NaN
2018-10-17  5  6.0  2  5.0  NaN   NaN
2018-10-18  4  1.0  6  5.0  NaN   NaN
2018-10-19  4  3.0  7  9.0  NaN   NaN
2018-10-20  7  6.0  7  5.0  NaN   NaN
2018-10-21  1  NaN  9  NaN  4.0  10.0
2018-10-22  1  NaN  6  NaN  4.0   6.0
```

Now the only issue would be the RAM you have at your disposal, and since that wasn't mentioned, I'm assuming this is sufficient. If you *are* looking for a more memory-optimized solution, we would have to see how those frames are created, since pandas will always load the entire structure into RAM